# Mongo + Ruby Rails: get all embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

Another basic Mongo / Rails question.  I have a `Leagues` Model which embeds `Teams`, it should be really simple but I can't get a result of all teams across all the leagues. Can anyone help?

The only way I have done it so far is this

```
arrTeamsOut = Array.new

    @leagues = League.all
    @leagues.each do |league|
      league.teams.each do |team|
        arrTeamsOut.push(team)
        end
    end
```

Which creates an array which isn't ideal.

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: embeds_many :teams   and embedded_in :league

Comment: Sorry I am using Mongoid - is that what you where asking?

Comment: @user2503775 ORM is Object-relational mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
League.all.map(&:teams)
```

Comment: Thank you. `League.all.map(&:teams)`  works in that it gave me a collection of teams per league. So a count on `League.all.map(&:teams)` gave me three. If I do an each on the results and then a count, I got the correct numbers of teams in each league.   It would be great to get them all back in one collection but this works for me :)   `.pluck` gave me an error.